# Justifing letters html5 canvas - Js fiddle example

Tags: javascript, canvas

[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/beingalex1981/mWw3F/5/) - The larger the string in length the more space is added to the right.

I am trying to create some code that justifies text on canvas:

```
var ctx = this.ctx; // Is now canvas context

var str = 'A random string';

var width = 500; // The size that the string should fit to

var strWidth = this.ctx.measureText(str); // The width in pixels of the string when it's put on canvas

var chars = str.split(''); // Make an array of string

var space = (width - strWidth.width) / (chars.length - 1);

var xpos = 1; // Start of text X position 

this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,750,750);

    var ctx = this.ctx;

Array.each(chars, function(char) {
    ctx.fillText(char, xpos, 1);  
    xpos += space.toInt();          
});
```

I don't want the words to be justified, instead I would like the letters to be justified.

Basically this iterates over the string's characters and draws them onto the canvas with added spacing between each character to FILL a certain width. This code seems to add too much spacing to the right. The larger the string in character length the more space is added  to the right.

I think it may be something to do with the `space` variable  calculation. I am trying to fit a random length string into a specific space by lengthening the space between each character.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close but you are only adding width of the space and forget to add the width of the char as well:

Try this and it should work:

```
xpos += space + ctx.measureText(char).width;
```

**[MODIFIED FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/mWw3F/7/)**

Also for more accuracy you should not round your spacing to integer value. Canvas can handle sub-pixeling and it will give a better result (I modified this in the fiddle as well in canvas to demonstrate).

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you. I will mention you in the app.